# NSURLConnection chunked encoding upload - How?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, chunked-encoding

I need to create a way to upload a bytestream using chunked encoding.

I have a byte array that contains an audio file, I would like to send that file to a server using a chunked stream.

I've been able to do a chunked upload via a native socket but I would really like to do this via one of the NSURL (NSURLConnection?) libs. Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using ASIHTTPRequest, available here: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

Scroll way down to "Streaming request bodies directly from disk"

Answer (score 2):

My experience with the NSURLConnection classes has been awful. They are full of memory leaks.

After much trial and failure, I now use an iPhone compiled version of libcurl; it's far better, see here..

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/4580-curl-anyone-using-their-app.html

Comment: No idea why this was voted down, but I found myself in the same situation of having massive leaks when using NSURLConnection.