# NSURLConnection and "chunked" transfer-coding

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, http

Have read thru other source, such as: https://discussions.apple.com/message/7844057#7844057

Seems there is no way to read a page with "chunked" transfer-coding (i.e. without content-length) using `NSURLConnection`.

Any other workaround or other library can help?

**Update**: Finally solved by using ASIHTTPRequest

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283331/nsurlconnection-chunked-encoding-upload-how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/).

Answer (score 0):

It might be too late to re-architect everything, but an awful lot of people like [RestKit](http://restkit.org/). It is primarily for communication with Restful services, including some pretty powerful object mapping, but I do recall seeing some mention in the docs for batch transfers of large amounts of data, say image data. Perhaps it can help you with your chunks?