# URLSession didReceiveData isn't called in chunked request

Tags: swift, http, chunked-encoding, urlsession, http-chunked

I try to listen data from [dweet.io](https://dweet.io) service.
I use [listen](https://dweet.io/play/#!/dweets/listenForDweets_get_4) method to get data in realtime. It uses **chunked HTTP responses**.

I've created simple network manager for that

```swift
import Foundation

class NetworkManager: NSObject, URLSessionDataDelegate {
    private lazy var session = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: .main)
    private lazy var task = self.session
        .dataTask(with: URL(string: "https://dweet.io/listen/for/dweets/from/opposite-carpenter")!)

    func start() {
        self.task.resume()
    }

// THIS METHOD IS NEVER CALLED
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {
        print(data)
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
        print(error!.localizedDescription)
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive response: URLResponse, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.ResponseDisposition) -> Void) {
        print(response)
        completionHandler(.allow)
    }
}
```

When I start it I never get data. However I'm getting response with 200 status code and headers. And after about a minute I get an error *`The network connection was lost.`*

Simultaneously I use `curl` for the same thing. And it's getting data as expected.

```sh
curl -i "https://dweet.io/listen/for/dweets/from/subdued-nation"
```

Another thing I was confused by is that iOS app and curl show me different values in `Transfer-Encoding` field in headers:

`UrlSession` returns  `"Transfer-Encoding" : "Identity"`.

At the same time curl shows `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` (which is expected).

I've tried to apply approach described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46082597/4315868) but I got the same result.

Comment: Let's make sure the problem is with the URL and not with your code. If you change `URL(string: "https://dweet.io/listen/for/dweets/from/opposite-carpenter")` to `URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")`, does the data get printed in the console?

Comment: Also you say "after about a minute". That sounds like you're timing out, since one minute is exactly the default value of a URLSessionConfiguration `timeoutIntervalForRequest`. Is this a connection that needs to be kept open for longer than that?

Comment: @matt you're right. If I use apple.com as url that's working fine. Cause that's ordinary HTTP request. But how can I handle HTTPS-streams?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that the problem is the phrase `URLSession(configuration: .default`. Using the `default` configuration, you time out after one minute. That, presumably, is not what you want.

Comment: Definitely no. Within this minute I can create few data chunks, get HTTP response in NetworkManager, get data with `curl` but don't get data in session delegate.

Comment: Well it was just a wild guess! Sorry not to be any help. :(