# Swift - Using URLSessionStreamTask to keep my app in sync with Firebase DB data

Tags: swift, firebase, rest, firebase-realtime-database

I came across [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44602192/how-to-use-urlsessionstreamtask-with-urlsession-for-chunked-encoding-transfer) trying to figure out how to access the REST api of my firebase database and stream it to my app. I can get/send data manually, but for my app I can't use the firebase api (because it is an app clip), so I'm trying to do it with native tools and rest, but the issue I'm running into is getting the configuration right (per [this info](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-streaming)) and actually parsing the incoming info and updating my app. I'm so lost and could use some help just figuring out how to make the code in the sample work, especially since I'm using swift ui as well.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently App Clips do not allow sockets connections, so (while Google rewrites their sdk to comply), I migrated my database to Realtime Database (since it was a better fit for us usage-wise), and have been using standard rest for sending and getting data, and for the "listener" functionality I have been using [IKEventSource](https://github.com/inaka/EventSource) that listens to server-side events and updates them accordingly in my app clip. Seems to be a pretty good workaround so far.